# WPF storyboard not running animations in parallel

Tags: wpf, xaml, storyboard

I am trying to animate the main window, changing the width and the height. I use a DataTrigger in the main window style to change it but when I run it first triggers the width change and then the height change, I want both of them changing at the same time.

```
<Storyboard x:Key="TransitToExecution">
    <!-- This animation hides the main panel -->
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Duration="0:0:0.5">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="{StaticResource ScreenHeight}"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Duration="0:0:0.5">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="{StaticResource ScreenWidth}"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

The data trigger is very simple:

```
    <Window.Style>
    <Style>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsWideScreen}" Value="true" >
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource TransitToExecution}"/>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Style>
```

Any ideas why these two animations do not run simultaneuosly?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried swapping the animations around to see if the effect is independent of which properties you are animating?

Comment: Whichever I put first runs fine, the second one just suddenly appears once the time has passed. I was wondering if is something related to the width and height that can not be set together

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem possible to animate both the `Width` and `Height` of a Window at the same time without some effort; a solution was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332385/animating-a-wpf-window-width-and-height). Alternatively, you could queue the animations:

```xaml
<BeginStoryboard HandoffBehavior="Compose">
  <Storyboard>
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="window name"
      Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
      From="130" To="600" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="window name"
      Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
      From="300" To="800" Duration="0:0:0.5" BeginTime="0:0:0.5"/>
  </Storyboard>
</BeginStoryboard>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to have two BeginStoryboards in your trigger - one for the width, one for the height.

```
<Storyboard x:Key="TransitToExecutionHeight">
    <!-- This animation hides the main panel -->
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Duration="0:0:0.5">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="{StaticResource ScreenHeight}"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
<Storyboard x:Key="TransitToExecutionWidth">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Duration="0:0:0.5">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="{StaticResource ScreenWidth}"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

And then in your Trigger:

```
    <Window.Style>
    <Style>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsWideScreen}" Value="true" >
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource TransitToExecutionWidth}"/>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource TransitToExecutionHeight}"/>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Style>
```

Comment: No, actually does not work either. It seems that it can move the window height and width at the same time.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment.  Do you mean it *cannot* move the height and width at the same time?  If this is true, it may be either a .NET 4.0 or an EasingDoubleKeyFrame issue - I will defer to other experts on this, as I don't have that available in front of me at the moment.  All I can say (for the moment, anyway) is that I can get width and height to change at the same time using a LinearDoubleKeyFrame in .NET 3.5.