# WPF Storyboard can't resize window width with height

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to resize a WPF window using `Storyboard`. My code works perfectly when I animate the window width or height, but when I'm applying a storyboard on both of them it animates only the first property (width in my case) and skips on the second one.

My code is:

```
    private void AnimateWindowSize(double width, double height, bool isRelative = false)
    {
        //---------------------------------------------------
        //  Settings
        //---------------------------------------------------

        var duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.2);
        var newWidth = isRelative ? this.Width - width : width;
        var newHeight = isRelative ? this.Height - height : height;

        Console.WriteLine($"Animating window from {this.Width}x{this.Height} to {newWidth}x{newHeight}");

        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            var storyboard = new Storyboard();

            //---------------------------------------------------
            //  Animate Width
            //---------------------------------------------------
            var widthAnimation = new DoubleAnimation()
            {
                Duration = new Duration(duration),
                From = this.ActualWidth,
                To = newWidth
            };

            Storyboard.SetTarget(widthAnimation, this);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(widthAnimation, new PropertyPath(Window.WidthProperty));
            storyboard.Children.Add(widthAnimation);

            //---------------------------------------------------
            //  Animate Width
            //---------------------------------------------------
            var heightAnimation = new DoubleAnimation()
            {
                Duration = new Duration(duration),
                From = this.ActualHeight,
                To = newHeight
            };

            Storyboard.SetTarget(heightAnimation, this);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(heightAnimation, new PropertyPath(Window.HeightProperty));
            storyboard.Children.Add(heightAnimation);

            //---------------------------------------------------
            //  Play
            //---------------------------------------------------
            //storyboard.Begin();
            this.BeginStoryboard(storyboard, HandoffBehavior.SnapshotAndReplace, false);
        }), null);
    }
```

BTW, I've created a generic version of this method for animating the sizes of my menus etc and it works perfectly. It seems to be only a problem with the Window animation. Does anyone knows how to fix it and apply animation for both window width and height? I followed after answers in SO but all of them related to elements other then Window.

Answer (score 0):

remove the duration from the heightAnimation.

Comment: Thanks :). Removing the duration of the heightAnimaion really results in the 2 animation execution, but they won't run in parallel, so the width and height will be resized at the same time. When I've removed the duration the window resizing its width and only then its height.

Comment: Hi, you can not animate width and height parallel, here you can find a workaround https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332385/animating-a-wpf-window-width-and-height